# Python 3 - installing pygal

Tags: python-3.x, module, pygal

I am new to Python, this might be a silly question but here goes:

I'm getting an error trying to install pygall for python3:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRuIE.png)

Thanks,
Mihnea

Comment: There seems to be a connectivity issue. I used to have this issue when I'm on VPN which blocks some connections to open Internet. If that't the case, get off VPN.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install Python packages \[SSL: TLSV1\_ALERT\_PROTOCOL\_VERSION\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)