# Not able to install Python packages [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION]

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, ssl-certificate

I am trying to install a Python library using `pip`, getting an SSL error:

```
~/projects/base  pre-master±  pip install xdict

Collecting xdict
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/xdict/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xdict (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for xdict
```

pip version: pip 9.0.1

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Follow this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46808948/2419644

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to install python libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49734434/unable-to-install-python-libraries)

Comment: Make sure you have the correct openssl version. Then recompile the Python with the openssl path.

Comment: make sure you have the correct openssl version.

Comment: Not sure if you/anyone insist on the `Brew` python version, i wasn't. so I installed the latest version directly from https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/, double click - and that's it. everything works.

Answer (score 452, accepted):

Upgrade pip as follows:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

Note: You may need to use `sudo python` above if not in a virtual environment.

(Note that upgrading `pip` using `pip` i.e `pip install --upgrade pip` will also not upgrade it correctly. It's just a chicken-and-egg issue. `pip` won't work unless using TLS >= 1.2.)

As mentioned in [this detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49748494/1526703), this is due to the recent TLS deprecation for pip. Python.org sites have [stopped support](https://status.python.org/incidents/hdx7w97m5hr8) for TLS versions 1.0 and 1.1.

From the Python status page:

> **Completed** - The rolling brownouts are finished, and TLSv1.0 and
>   TLSv1.1 have been disabled. Apr 11, 15:37 UTC

**For PyCharm (virtualenv) users:**

1. Run virtual environment with shell. (replace "./venv/bin/activate" to your own path)

   ```
   source ./venv/bin/activate
   ```
2. Run upgrade

   ```
   curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
   ```
3. Restart your PyCharm instance, and check your Python interpreter in *Preference*.

Comment: This worked for me! I had to add `sudo` at the front because of permission denied errors. Thanks!

Comment: Requires sudo to work:

`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python`

Comment: @Simar @Wallace yeah, may require `sudo` if not in a virtual environment. Added that bit as well in the answer now.

Comment: If you're not in a virtual environment you may need to specify the path to your python binary, as Ilya mentions below

Comment: On OSX this worked better for me `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo -H python3`

Comment: `curl: (35) error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version`

Comment: This Solution dint work for me. On OSX, I use @nickfox solution,  I started getting some other errors   ERROR: Compiling fastdtw because it depends on /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Cython/Includes/numpy/math.pxd. saw this error down the way, Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/pytest-runner/. I installed pytest-runner separately, I was able to install and solve my probelm

Comment: I needed to run:
sudo -H pip3.5 install requests[security]
afterwards, too.

Comment: This curl command seems to do nothing for eternity.

Comment: @2540625 try running https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py in your browser - does it return the py file?

Comment: I'm stuck with Python 2.6.6 - the script doesn't work with anything older than Python 3.6.

Comment: On a MacOS Ventura v13.2.1, I got this to work:
`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py | sudo python2`
and got me to pip 20.3.4

Answer (score 31):

But if the `curl` command itself fails with error, or **"tlsv1 alert protocol version"** persists even after upgrading `pip`, it means your operating system's underlying OpenSSL library version<`1.0.1` or Python version<`2.7.9` (or <`3.4` in Python 3) do not support the newer TLS 1.2 protocol that `pip` needs to connect to PyPI since [about a year ago](https://pyfound.blogspot.com/2017/01/time-to-upgrade-your-python-tls-v12.html). You can easily check it in Python interpreter:

```
>>> import ssl
>>> ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
'OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010'
>>> ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2'
```

The `AttributeError` (instead of expected '5') means your Python stdlib `ssl` module, compiled against old openssl lib, is lacking support for the TLSv1.2 protocol (even if the openssl library can or could be updated later).

Fortunately, it can be solved *without upgrading Python* (and the whole system), by manually installing extra Python packages -- the detailed step-by-step guide is [available here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54582701/9575715).

> Note, `curl` and `pip` and `wget` all depend on the same OpenSSL lib for establishing SSL connections (use `$ openssl version` command). libcurl supports TLS 1.2 since curl version [7.34](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2016-07/0031.html), but older curl versions [should](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2015-07/0133.html) be able to connect *if* you had OpenSSL version 1.0.2 (or later).
>
> ---
>
> **P.S.**
>   For *Python 3*, please use `python3` and `pip3` everywhere (unless you are in a venv/virtualenv), including the `curl` command from [above](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/):
>   `$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3 --user`

Comment: I also realized I had to run `pip3`, not just `pip` — check version with command `-V` to make sure you're running the right pip!!

Answer (score 9):

Following @Anupam's answer on OS X resulted in the following error for me, regardless of permissions I ran it with:

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: ...

What eventually worked was to download a newer pip package (9.0.3) from PyPI directly from my browser - https://pypi.org/simple/pip/, extract the contents, and then pip install the package locally:

```
pip install ./pip-9.0.3/
```

This fixed my `[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION]` errors.

Answer (score 7):

[@Anupam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49769015/1129332)'s solution worked for me. However, I had to use `sudo` and specify the exact location of my virtual Python environment:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo /Users/{your user name}/{path to python}/bin/python
```

Answer (score 6):

To upgrade the local version I used a slight variant:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python - --user
```

This problem arises if you keep your pip and packages under your home directory as described in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/rxm/0c3eaade72ed45587d908dd18a3e2195).

Answer (score 5):

Check your TLS version:

```
python2 -c "import urllib2,json; print(json.loads(urllib2.urlopen('https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check').read())['tls_version'])"
```

If your TLS version is less than 1.2 you have to upgrade it since the PyPI repository is on a brownout period of deprecating early TLS.

Source - [Time To Upgrade Your Python: TLS v1.2 Will Soon Be Mandatory](https://pyfound.blogspot.com/2017/01/time-to-upgrade-your-python-tls-v12.html)

You can upgrade the TLS version using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install openssl libssl-dev
```

This should fix your problem.
Good luck!

EDIT: 
You can download packages using your own private python package repository regardless of TLS version. 
[Private Python Package Repository](https://medium.com/@vithulanmv.12/custom-python-pypi-repository-409f14975374)

Answer (score 5):

The following solution worked for me:

```
brew install python2
```

It also upgraded `pip` to version 1.10.1

Comment: ^ this one for those of us not using the default python on OSX. I guess the question wasn't OSX specific, but anyway, if you're not running Linux, this works --- unless you're content writing over the system installed Python.

Comment: This one worked for me, I use the python on OSX. My situation I spent a week trying to install any pip package and it failed. I uninstalled pip and from this time I can not do anything till I got this command which installed pip for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

For all the `python3` and `pip3` users out there:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python3
```

and then assume you want to install pandas

```
pip3 install pandas --user
```

Answer (score 2):

For Python2 WIN10 Users:

1.Uninstall python thoroughly ,include all folders.

2.Fetch and install the lastest python-2.7.msi (ver 2.7.15)

3.After step 2,you may find pip had been installed too.

4.Now ,if your system'env haven't been changed,you can use pip to install packages now.The "tlsv1 alert protocol version" will not appear.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. Add sudo before python

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py |sudo python
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried all existing fixes and not working for me

I re-install python 2.7 (will also install pip) by downloading .pkg at https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/

works for me after installation downloaded pkg

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem as well. The underlying problem is that the ssl library in Python 2.7 versions < 2.7.9 is no longer compatible with the pip mechanism.

If you are running on Windows, and you (like us) can't easily upgrade from an incompatible version of 2.7, FWIW, I found that if you copy the following files from another install of the latest version of Python (e.g. Python 2.7.15) on another machine to your installation:

```
    Lib\ssl.py
    libs\_ssl.lib
    DLLs\_ssl.dll
```

it will effectively "upgrade" your SSL layer to one which is supported; we were then be able to use pip again, even to upgrade pip.

Answer (score 2):

The answers of installing pip via:

1. `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py |sudo python` or
2. `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python`

did not work for me as I kept on getting the error:

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip
```

I had to install `pip` manually via:

1. Go the `pip` distribution [website](https://pypi.org/project/pip/#files)
2. Download the `tar.gz` version
3. Unpack the file locally and `cd` into the directory
4. run `python setup.py install`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, I installed latest version of pip and then installed the library (**ciscoconfparse**).

Upgrading pip:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo /Users/{your user name}/{path to python}/bin/python
```

Answer (score 1):

I also hit this problem on my windows10 and tried all the answers but didn't solve my problem.

> C:\python367\Scripts>pip install Flask
>
> Collecting Flask   Could not find a version that satisfies the
>   requirement Flask (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for
>   Flask

After that, I find the pip configuration file had been modified. So, I set the `pip.ini` as the original default configuration, re-run the pip command and it works for me!

In summary of the solution of mine:

1. Check the pip.ini (usually under the path `C:\ProgramData\pip`) had been modified;
2. If yes in step1, try to reset it to a default configuration.

Answer (score 1):

myenv:

python 2.7.14

pip 9.0.1

mac osx 10.9.4

---

mysolution:

1. download `get-pip.py` manually from https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/
2. run `python get-pip.py`

---

refs:

https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/issues/3293#issuecomment-378468534

https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/

> Securely Download get-pip.py [1]
>
> Run python get-pip.py. [2] This will install or upgrade pip. Additionally, it will install setuptools and wheel if they’re not installed already.
>
> Ensure pip, setuptools, and wheel are up to date
>
> While pip alone is sufficient to install from pre-built binary archives, up to date copies of the setuptools and wheel projects are useful to ensure you can also install from source archives:
>
> `python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`

Answer (score 1):

Or simply the required library just isn't in the repo. I'm Python newbie and all advices about upgrading pip finally shown as misleading. I had just to look into https://pypi.org/ , finding the library (airflow in my case) stopped at some old version, after which it was renamed. Yes, also that silly solution is also possible :-).