# Python issue installing pip/packages windows

Tags: python, proxy

I have some issues to install package in Python.

Python version : 3.5.2

I used "`pip install --upgrade pip`" to reach the 9.0.3 version but I had proxy issues.

Then, I used the following command to set proxy variable :

`set http_proxy=http://pseudo%20space:mdp%2Dtiret@proxy:port`

`set https_proxy=https://pseudo%20space:mdp%2Dtiret@proxy:port`

Finally I use :

```
pip install --upgrade --proxy=https://pseudo%20space:mdp%2Dtiret@proxy:port pip
```

I get :

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]....
```

(I have the admin rights)

Edit :
- It is not a specific issue with pip, I can not install any package

Comment: Are you on VPN or something> Your connection seems to be blocked. You can try to go off VPN or if you have to be on VPN, there should be an artifact that can be reached to install packages for the environment you are in.

Comment: Yes I'm on a kind of VPN but I get the authorization/activation to bypass/pass through the proxy so basically it should work I think

Comment: Have you tried running this directly in your terminal: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py?

Comment: I download the python script and I use "python get-pip.py"
Then I get the same kind of error :
"Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool<host='pypi.python.org', port=443>: Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ <Caused by SSLError<SSLError<1,' [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]..."

Comment: How about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install python packages \[SSL: TLSV1\_ALERT\_PROTOCOL\_VERSION\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

Comment: I test "pip install --upgrade --trusted-host pypi.python.org pip"
- It downloaded pip-10.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
- It found existing packages pip 8.1.1 and uninstalled it
then I get an exception, permission error and several exception
When I try 'pip --version', I get "Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using..."

Comment: Finally it seems that it worked pretty well with 'python -m pip install --upgrade --proxy=http://name:password@proxy:port --trusted-host pypi.python.org packageName'
I installed the newest version of pip and also some tools like tensorflow, thanks Yilun Zhang!

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer of its own, not as an edit.

Comment: I moved your solution to a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade command

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

does not work on Windows because the program attempts to delete itself while it is running. In Windows you need to do

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Thank for the answer, I tested it and I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

Issues fixed with:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade --proxy=http://name:password@proxy:port --trusted-host pypi.python.org packageName
```