# Not able to install any library [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION]

Tags: python, ssl, terminal, openssl, ssl-certificate

**Operating system**: Mac OS 10.12.6 
**Python**: I would like to install on 3.5 but there might be a confusion as you can see down here 
**pip version**: 8.1.2

First I was trying to install a library called scrapy using `pip install scrapy`. This happened:

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/:
There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION]
tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:646) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 10.0.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

It suggested me to upgrade my pip, so I did `pip install --upgrade pip` and surprise:

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/:
There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION]
tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:646) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 10.0.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

One thing I noticed is that terminal is "talking" to Python 3.5 (as you can see in the error text above) however if I `python --version` it returns Python 2.7.10.

So then I tried `pip3 install scrapy`. Same result.

I tried many suggestions from other posts and nothing works. I'm going nuts here.
Could someone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install python packages \[SSL: TLSV1\_ALERT\_PROTOCOL\_VERSION\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one answered, I had to follow on my own. The solution I found is not ideal but it worked. [I installed Anaconda](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/macos.html) and set it as my virtual environment. In that way I managed to either use scrapy (library I was looking for) as well as install other libraries.