# Error while installing jupyter

Tags: python, pip, jupyter

I'm getting below error while installing Jupiter, does anyone came across similar issues.

```
pip3.5 install jupyter
    Collecting jupyter
    /grid/common/pkgs/python/v3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
      SNIMissingWarning
      Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/jupyter/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:645) - skipping
      Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jupyter (from versions: )
    No matching distribution found for jupyter


    Here are the env details

    OS:   RHEL6

    Python -  3.5.2
    Pip:  9.0.1
    Curl:   7.47.1
    Openssl 1.0.1e
```

Comment: Your error says "You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this.".What version of python are you using.Did u try pip install jupyter , pip3 install jupyter ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install python packages \[SSL: TLSV1\_ALERT\_PROTOCOL\_VERSION\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

Comment: @AniketBote,  Python Version -  3.5.2

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Go to Python root folder and run the "Install Certificates.command" file.
2. You may follow https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BVS3U1OQzO4