# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask

Tags: python, pip

[Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2gR4.jpg)
pip install -U Flask

Collecting Flask
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/flask/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask (from versions: )

No matching distribution found for Flask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install python packages \[SSL: TLSV1\_ALERT\_PROTOCOL\_VERSION\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

Answer (score 1):

This is cause by flakiness in PYPI CDN, which was migrated mid April 2018.

We still encounter these problems every day, probably in 1% of builds.

I tried to get an ack on #pypi irc channel but getting the issue confirmed is still a TODO.