# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement snowflake-connector-python==2.3.6

Tags: python, pip, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I received this error when running `pip install -r requirements.txt` where `snowflake-connector-python==2.3.6` was included. Running `pip install snowflake-connector-python` works just fine.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50148273/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-flask) suggests it could be an issue with the PYPI CDN.

**How can I troubleshoot issues like this in the future?**

I'll post the main errors along with an image since the latter is easier to read IMO.

> WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/09/39/65b33cf8ea5a1a6ecc213b8beba65f3860440bd5c4a8c5636e2b8d23afa9/snowflake-connector-python-2.3.6.tar.gz#sha256=1a4ebf25989fc13d6f70dc3e2064721c54834e493a7964a1d67be61d40e75f50 (from https://pypi.org/simple/snowflake-connector-python/) (requires-python:>=3.5). Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/willwright/miniconda3/bin/python /private/var/folders/c8/9c921tr17gdbjsfbrw4hlgtr0000gn/T/pip-standalone-pip-12vdp_4t/**env_pip**.zip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/c8/9c921tr17gdbjsfbrw4hlgtr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-8eydzsmj/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.6.0' wheel cython 'pyarrow>=0.17.0,<0.18.0' Check the logs for full command output.

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement snowflake-connector-python==2.3.6 (from versions: 1.3.17, 1.3.18, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4.9, 1.4.10, 1.4.11, 1.4.12, 1.4.13, 1.4.14, 1.4.15, 1.4.16, 1.4.17, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.6.6, 1.6.7, 1.6.8, 1.6.9, 1.6.10, 1.6.11, 1.6.12, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.7.7, 1.7.8, 1.7.9, 1.7.10, 1.7.11, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.8.7, 1.9.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.2.4, 2.2.5, 2.2.6, 2.2.7, 2.2.8, 2.2.9, 2.2.10, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.3.5, 2.3.6, 2.3.7, 2.3.8, 2.3.9, 2.3.10, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4, 2.4.5, 2.4.6, 2.5.0, 2.5.1)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for snowflake-connector-python==2.3.6

[image: snowflake-connector_error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was on the wrong virtual environment -- this version of the snowflake connector doesn't work with python 3.9. I needed to switch from the default venv to the one I created with python 3.8:

```sh
conda create -n "myenv" python=3.8
conda deactivate
conda activate myenv
```