# Can't install PySocks MacOS 10.13 python 2.7.13

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

Can't install PySocks on my Mac. Python version 2.7.13.
I'm using `pip install PySocks` and getting this message:

```
Collecting pysocks
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pysocks/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:661) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pysocks (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pysocks
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install python packages \[SSL: TLSV1\_ALERT\_PROTOCOL\_VERSION\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

Answer (score 0):

```
There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

try to disabe the SSL Certificate Check for The Site https://pypi.python.org/simple/pysocks/

or There Are A 404 Not Found Or An 403 Forbidden In The Site

Comment: Thanks! I can open the site there is no error. Will try to disable SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the old version of pip. Tried to upgrade pip via `pip install --upgrade pip` but id doesn't work. So found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49769015/5635809).