# pip 9.0.1 upgrade behind proxy

Tags: python, windows, pip

This command:

```
pip.exe --proxy=<my proxy> install python_telegram_bot-10.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

gives error:

```
Collecting future>=0.16.0 (from python-telegram-bot==10.1.0)
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/future/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:590) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement future>=0.16.0 (from python-telegram-bot==10.1.0) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for future>=0.16.0 (from python-telegram-bot==10.1.0)
```

I found that problem with SSL certificate is because I have version of pip 9.0.1. So I decided to upgrade it, following instructions from [pip installation instructions](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/).

I tried this:

```
python.exe -m pip --proxy=<my proxy> install --trusted-host=pypi.python.org --upgrade pip
```

With result:

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:590) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Which suggests me to use exact command which lead to the problem.

Is there a way somehow to solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install python packages \[SSL: TLSV1\_ALERT\_PROTOCOL\_VERSION\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

Comment: No it's not. I've been trying to reinstall with "get-pip.py" from the beginning: it doesn't work also.