# "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement" error for Django2 app installation

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pip, setuptools

I'm newbie Python/Django programmer.

I created an application based on Django 2.0 and packaged it according to [the official document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/reusable-apps/).
Then I run the command:

```
$ pip install --user django-easybuggy-0.1.tar.gz
```

However, I get the error and cannot install.

```
Processing ./django-easybuggy-0.1.tar.gz
Collecting certifi==2018.1.18 (from django-easybuggy==0.1)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement certifi==2018.1.18 (from django-easybuggy==0.1) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for certifi==2018.1.18 (from django-easybuggy==0.1)
```

Does anyone know the reason why the error occurs and how to fix it?

In addition, I created `requirements.txt` by the command:

```
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Download my application archive:

   ```
   $ wget https://github.com/k-tamura/easybuggy4django/releases/download/0.0.1/django-easybuggy-0.1.tar.gz
   ```
2. Run the command:

   ```
   $ pip install --user django-easybuggy-0.1.tar.gz
   ```

Best regards,

Comment: what `pip` version are you? `pip -V` Could be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49768770/1526703)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. `$ pip -V` shows : `pip 10.0.1 from /home/tamura/PycharmProjects/practice3/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can fix my problem by adding options:

```
--proxy=http://[proxy_user_id]:[proxy_user_password]@[proxy_host]:[proxy_port]/ --trusted-host pypi.python.org  --trusted-host pypi.org  --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org
```

to `pip install`.

Answer (score 1):

The package `certifi==2018.1.18` was removed from PyPI. The current version is `certifi==2018.4.16`. The reason for this is that `certifi` is somewhat special: it is nothing else but a collection of root SSL certificates, so once they become stale and a new version of `certifi` with new certs is released, the old ones are being deleted for security reasons - so you don't accidentally continue to install and use old and potentially revoked or compromised certificates.

The solution for you is to either drop the exact version requirement alltogether:

```
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=['certifi'],
    ...
)
```

or to require a minimal version and (optionally) bump it with new releases of your package:

```
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=['certifi>=2018.4.16'],
    ...
)
```

The latter is what I usually use: this way,

1. you always know a minimum version of the requirement you've tested with (and thus know that your package works fine with it),
2. if the user happens to have an old version of `certifi` installed, it will be upgraded automatically to the currently newest one when your package is installed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your answer may be one of the solution of my question but it cannot be applied to my case (vote+1).