# Error installing a python package from github in canopy terminal

Tags: python, terminal, installation, pip, canopy

I am trying to install [orbital.py](https://github.com/RazerM/orbital) from github using the canopy command line and pip install.

The terminal is not letting me copy and paste the error message so I will include a picture.

The main issue seems to be `raise SSLError(e, request=request) SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590)`[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install python packages \[SSL: TLSV1\_ALERT\_PROTOCOL\_VERSION\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this package is on PyPy, so you can just install it like this

```
pip install orbitalpy
```

If you want to install the latest version from github, you can install it like this

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/RazerM/orbital.git#egg=orbital
```

Comment: I orginally tried `pip install` and it returned `could not find a version that satisfies the requirement orbitalpy (from versions: ) No matching distributions found for orbitalpy`

Comment: I also tried the second version you posted and got the same error message

Comment: Once I updated Canopy `pip install -e git+https://github.com/RazerM/orbital.git#egg=orbital` worked great

Answer (score 1):

From the SSL error, I suspect that you're running an old version of Canopy. What version are you running?

The current version is 2.1.9. To update Canopy, and for a link to release notes, please see ["Installing a new Canopy version"](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469570-Installing-a-new-Canopy-version).