# SSLError : Issue while installing packages using pip on naoqi version 2.1.4

Tags: python, pip, nao-robot

While installing packages in Naoqi version *2.1.4* getting below SSL error:

> There was a problem confirming the SSL certificate:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/google-cloud/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:504: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)) - skipping

- Pip version: pip 9.0.3
- Python version: Python 2.7.3

Comment: Try upgrading to newer version of python

Comment: Can you check the date of your robot ? Sometimes the robot date is reset to a few years past, which causes SSL certificates to be considered invalid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install python packages \[SSL: TLSV1\_ALERT\_PROTOCOL\_VERSION\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)