# Not able to install pexpect using pip

Tags: python, pip, pexpect

I am not able to install pexpect using pip. Here is the error:

```
$ sudo -H pip install pexpect
Collecting pexpect
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pexpect (from 
versions: )
No matching distribution found for pexpect

$ sudo -H pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Python/2.7/site- 
packages
$ python --version
Python 2.7.10
```

Could someone please point me what could be the issue?
Thanks

I tried brew and easy_install as well. None of them worked:

```
$ sudo -H easy_install pexpect

Searching for pexpect
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pexpect/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/pexpect/: [SSL: 
TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) 
-- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'pexpect' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [SSL: 
TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) 
-- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for pexpect
error: Could not find suitable distribution for 
Requirement.parse('pexpect')

$ brew install pexpect
Error: No available formula with the name "pexpect"
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
==> Searching local taps...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

I checked the site: https://pypi.python.org/simple/pexpect/ . I do not see files for python 2.7 version. That could be the reason. Does anyone know how can i get pexpect for Python 2.7 or any other solution.

Comment: Why are you using the system python?

Comment: Install Python from either a) Python website or b) from Homebrew.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install python packages \[SSL: TLSV1\_ALERT\_PROTOCOL\_VERSION\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

Comment: It is not same issue as mentioned in previous link.

Answer (score 0):

I found an odd result on a fresh install.  I was unable to install anything with pip3 until I ran python once.  Ran `python -V` and then had no problems.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: Well it is not a root cause for certain, but running python -v just once fixed my problem.  So at worst I'd call it a pragmatic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Like 'Ray Mo', upgrading pip2 was the solution for me. It seems that pexpect now has a version dependency on pip.

**However**, pip dropped support for python2 from version 21 onwards, so you need to install version 20 e.g.

`sudo python2 -m pip install --upgrade pip>=20,<21`

Now pexpect will install.

Answer (score -1):

**pip** was not installing till it was upgraded.

I first had to update `pip` with the following command:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

- If `pip` does not properly `upgrade` on the first attempt, rerun the command.
- Once `pip` has upgraded successfully, installing `pexpect` is a piece of cake.