# 'tlsv1 alert protocol version' error with recent versions of Python/Pip

Tags: python, centos

I have been attempting this:

```
$ pip3.5 install --upgrade praw
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/praw/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:719) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: praw in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/decorator/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:719) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: decorator<4.1,>=4.0.9 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from praw)
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/prawcore/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:719) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: prawcore<0.3,>=0.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from praw)
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/requests/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:719) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: requests>=2.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from praw)
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/six/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:719) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: six==1.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from praw)
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/update-checker/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:719) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: update_checker==0.11 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from praw)
```

I checked to see if Pip was recent:

> pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)

And Python:

> Python 3.5.5

OpenSSL:

> OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018

urllib is installed:

> Requirement already satisfied: urllib3[secure] in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages

What am I missing that causes this TLS v1 error?

I did upgrade Python from 3.5.1 to 3.5.5 thinking that would solve it, as it's from 2018.

Comment: update pip to latest version 10.0.1. Also the warning states that  **You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this**

Comment: @SmartManoj Is there a specific reason 3.5.5 is not enough? I did just upgrade to 3.5.5

Comment: `pip install urllib3[secure]` Try this

Comment: @SmartManoj That looks like it is already all set: `Requirement already satisfied: urllib3[secure] in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages`

Comment: did u update pip or update python to 3.6.5

Comment: @SmartManoj Trying to update pip gave me: `curl: (35) error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version`

Comment: [Not able to install Python packages SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49769015)

Comment: @SmartManoj Yes I followed that (curl) and that is the error I got.

Comment: Run this https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

Comment: @SmartManoj No luck, ran that script and got SSL errors

Comment: update python to 3.6.5 because pip is recently updated after python 3.5.5 [More](https://pyfound.blogspot.com/2017/01/time-to-upgrade-your-python-tls-v12.html)