# Error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pytest-runner')

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, pip, pypi

I tried to install MechanicalSoup package via pip but i got these errors :

```
    Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/pytest-runner/: [SSL: 
        TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version 
        (_ssl.c:645) -- 
    Some packages may not be found!
    Couldn't find index page for 'pytest-runner' (maybe misspelled?)
    No local packages or working download links found for pytest-runner
```

I tried several ways , but they could not help me .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install Python packages \[SSL: TLSV1\_ALERT\_PROTOCOL\_VERSION\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

Comment: I saw this post and did what he said but it could not solve my problem :|

Comment: You have to upgrade everything related to SSL — OpenSSL, Python, pip.

Answer (score 2):

First install pytest-runner as follows and try again:

```
pip3 install pytest-runner
```

or,

```
python3 -m pip install pytest-runner
```

You may want to add the --user tag if permission is denied.