# Pip Install SSL Issue

Tags: python, ssl, pip

I am getting the following SSL issue when running pip install:

```
python -m pip install zeep
Collecting zeep
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: 
Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify 
failed')],)",),)': /simple/zeep/
```

Comment: What's the time and date setting on your machine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install Python packages \[SSL: TLSV1\_ALERT\_PROTOCOL\_VERSION\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

Comment: Detail solution can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve the issue by using the following:

```
python -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --index-url=https://pypi.org/simple/ zeep
```

Answer (score 0):

If using windows then make sure the below three paths are added in Windows environment variable :

1. ....\Anaconda\Library\bin
2. ....\Anaconda\Scripts
3. ....\Anaconda

If not using Anaconda then in place of Anaconda the path where python is installed.