# I can't upgrade pip: Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a prόblem confirming the ssl certificate

Tags: python, terminal, pip

Trying to upgrade pip in my terminal. Here's my code:

```
(env) macbook-pro83:zappatest zorgan$ pip install --upgrade pip
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:645) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./env/lib/python3.5/site-packages
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Any idea what the problem is? I also get the same error `There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate` when I perform `pip install django`.

**Edit** `pip install --upgrade pip -vvv returns`:

```
1 location(s) to search for versions of pip:
* https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Looking up "https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/" in the cache
Returning cached "301 Moved Permanently" response (ignoring date and etag information)
Looking up "https://pypi.org/simple/pip/" in the cache
Current age based on date: 23811
Freshness lifetime from max-age: 600
Freshness lifetime from request max-age: 600
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:645) - skipping
Installed version (8.1.2) is most up-to-date (past versions: none)
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./env/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Cleaning up...
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install Python packages \[SSL: TLSV1\_ALERT\_PROTOCOL\_VERSION\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

Answer (score 5):

Managed to fix it (uninstall and reinstall pip) via the following command:

`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python`

Comment: This worked for me when nothing else did, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

a. Check your system date and time and see whether it is correct.

b. If the 1st solution doesn't fix it try using a lower security method:

```
pip install --index-url=http://pypi.python.org/simple/linkchecker
```

This bypasses HTTPS and uses HTTP instead, try this workaround only if you are in a hurry.

c. Try downgrading pip to a version that does not use SSL verification by:

```
pip install pip==1.2.1
```

and then upgrade pip back again to the newer version by:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

d. If nothing of the above works, uninstall pip and reinstall it.

Comment: Unfortunately neither of them worked. But I I manage to fix it with: `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python`. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can get more details about upgrade failed by using

`$ pip install --upgrade pip -vvv`

there will be more details help you debug it.

---

Try

`pip --trusted-host pypi.python.org install --upgrade pip`

Maybe useful.

---

Another solution:

`$ pip install certifi`

then run install.

Comment: I've added the output to that in my edit. I'm assuming it's saying the URL is wrong..? However `https://pypi.org/simple/pip/` still seems to be fine.

Comment: Get the same error on your second option unfortunately