# Error "pip install boto3"

Tags: python, macos, amazon-web-services, pip, boto3

```
$ pip install boto3
Collecting boto3
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/boto3/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:661) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement boto3 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for boto3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install fails with "connection error: \[SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED\] certificate verify failed (\_ssl.c:598)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install Python packages \[SSL: TLSV1\_ALERT\_PROTOCOL\_VERSION\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

Comment: A similar question is available and here's the answer you want to try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66649059/5355272

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Upgade pip as follows:

`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python`

It can be usefull for you, maybe you have to execute `sudo python`

Comment: correct way to upgrade pip is 
`pip install --upgrade pip`
or for windows : 
`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`