# python installing boto3 - could not find a version even though pypi shows th index

Tags: python, boto3, pypi

I got the following error when trying to install `boto3` from `python` on my mac

```
pip3 install boto
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement boto (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for boto
```

When I check on PyPi.org, I see results for boto3 package.

1. Any reason why this error comes up?
2. Any other index/option I could use?

I tried downloading the package from github and then installing it from source, but faced the same issue when installing one of the dependencies in boto3/requirements.txt.

Comment: Have you tried `pip3 install boto3` ?

Comment: yes, same response.

Comment: I also tried `curl` on pypi to see if I was blocked for some reason, but was able to `curl` and `wget` without any issues.

Comment: Also try including `boto3` in your `requirements.txt` manually.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to resolve this using a different index by using the `--extra-index-url` flag.

```
pip3 install --extra-index-url https://pypi.python.org/simple boto3

Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org, https://pypi.python.org/simple
Collecting boto3
  Downloading boto3-1.17.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (131 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 131 kB 1.1 MB/s
Collecting s3transfer<0.4.0,>=0.3.0
  Downloading s3transfer-0.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (69 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 69 kB 2.1 MB/s
Collecting botocore<1.21.0,>=1.20.28
  Downloading botocore-1.20.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.3 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 7.3 MB 4.9 MB/s
Collecting jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1
  Downloading jmespath-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.25.4
  Downloading urllib3-1.26.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (153 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 153 kB 3.9 MB/s
Collecting python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1
  Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 227 kB 2.3 MB/s
Collecting six>=1.5
  Downloading six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Installing collected packages: urllib3, jmespath, six, python-dateutil, botocore, s3transfer, boto3
Successfully installed boto3-1.17.28 botocore-1.20.28 jmespath-0.10.0 python-dateutil-2.8.1 s3transfer-0.3.4 six-1.15.0 urllib3-1.26.4
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I had to use an internal repository though as pypi access was blocked from the VMs

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was resolved after adding `--upgrade`.

Final command:  `pip3 install boto3 --upgrade`

Before :

```
$pip3 install boto3
Collecting boto3
  Using cached boto3-1.21.7-py3-none-any.whl (132 kB)
 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement botocore<1.25.0,>=1.24.7 (from boto3) (from versions: none)
 ERROR: No matching distribution found for botocore<1.25.0,>=1.24.7 (from boto3)
```

Answer (score 1):

As per official documentation to install boto3 run the following command:

```
pip install boto3
```

not `pip install boto`

Ref: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/quickstart.html#install-boto3

Comment: Tried this as well and got the same error

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve the problem by running the below commands:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org boto3
```

It's solved my problem, and hopefully it's useful for others too.