# No longer able to pip install: Could not fetch URL

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

Never had issues with `pip` until now. I am running Python 2.7 r27:82525 and pip 9.0.1 locally on Windows 7 64 bits. A virtual environment using the same Python version and pip 9.0.2 produces the same problem. No matter what package I tried to install, I always get the same URL fetching error:

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/psutil/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/psutil/ (Caused by S
SLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)) - skipping
```

I am also getting the `urllib3` `InsecurePlatformWarning` everybody seems to have too, in case it is related.

I can install a wheel file without any issues. The problem is the connection to the repository it seems.

edit: I have updated pip to version 10.0.1 and [OpenSSL for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm) but I am still having this problem. Using the `--trusted-flag` option does not help either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install Python packages \[SSL: TLSV1\_ALERT\_PROTOCOL\_VERSION\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

Comment: @phd all answers are for Linux

Comment: No, all answers are general. You have to upgrade OpenSSL, Python and pip.

Comment: @phd turns out upgrading Python solved it, so it *is* a duplicate. But I can't seem to be able to close the question, is it possible? If not, just post "upgrade python" as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: No need, just leave it alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the Python version I was running was too old. Upgrading it to 2.7.14 solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Please Use:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org <package_name>
```

Comment: SSL errors from pip can be ignored by adding pypi.org and files.pythonhosted.org as trusted hosts. I had troubles with SSLError and doing the above fixed it. I wouldn't know in great depth how and why it is doing so.

Comment: @PankajJoshi if you don't know "how and why" your "solution" fixed _your_ problem then you cannot know if it will fix the OP's problem too, so even if it accidentally happens to fix the issue, it's still a bad answer,  as it is cargo cult rather than knowledge, and SO is about sharing knowledge.

Comment: This didn't work either. It's not going around the SSL, still getting the error.