# Can't Install Tox

Tags: python, pip, installation, tox

I am using MacOs Sierra 10.12.6 , when I want to install Tox
(https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html ) .

```
~ $ pip install tox
Collecting tox
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/tox/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tox (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tox
~ $
```

How can I install Tox?

Comment: Is your pip updated?

Comment: Whats your `pip` and Python version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install Python packages \[SSL: TLSV1\_ALERT\_PROTOCOL\_VERSION\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

Comment: ~ $ pip --version 

pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)

Comment: We can't use pip or brew in our corporate environment. Manually installing tox 3.7.0  fails because it cannot find zipp>=0.5, even though zipp-2.1.0 is already installed. Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found simple solution :

> brew install python2