# pip3 install Flask-MongoEngine failing to install

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongoengine, setup.py, flask-mongoengine

I am tying to install Flask-MongoEngine with Python 3.4 which is what is installed on my Mac. When I attempt to install Flask-MongoEngine via pip3 I am getting the following error and not sure how to resolve it?

```
sudo pip3 install Flask-MongoEngine


    The directory '/Users/mastarke/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
    The directory '/Users/mastarke/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
    Collecting Flask-MongoEngine
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/20/53/1bb8ad34ad5c2047a11651290325e55086bc18fce7cfdbbe6f5522bd0ae5/flask-mongoengine-0.9.5.tar.gz (111kB)
        100% |████████████████████████████████| 194kB 4.0MB/s 
        Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
        Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/rednose/: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:600) -- Some packages may not be found!
        Couldn't find index page for 'rednose' (maybe misspelled?)
        Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:600) -- Some packages may not be found!
        No local packages or download links found for rednose
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "/private/tmp/pip-install-6wad5e5g/Flask-MongoEngine/setup.py", line 74, in <module>
            'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules'
          File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
            _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
          File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 269, in __init__
            self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
          File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_eggs
            replace_conflicting=True,
          File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 826, in resolve
            dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
          File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1092, in best_match
            return self.obtain(req, installer)
          File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1104, in obtain
            return installer(requirement)
          File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 380, in fetch_build_egg
            return cmd.easy_install(req)
          File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 658, in easy_install
            raise DistutilsError(msg)
        distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('rednose')

        ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-6wad5e5g/Flask-MongoEngine/
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install Python packages \[SSL: TLSV1\_ALERT\_PROTOCOL\_VERSION\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an issue with your company proxy.

Comment: This is a helpful answer. Switching to a different Internet connection resolved the issue for me.

Comment: yes, same for me also

Answer (score 0):

try installing it with pip instead of pip3 and then it mostly asks u to update it. This might help :
`python -m pip install –upgrade pip`

Comment: This is an old question, which probably was due to an issue mentioned here in the project's `setup.py`: https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=242785

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

`python -m pip install rednose nose coverage`

And then `install flask-mongoengine`