# Unable to PIP install Python ftfy package

Tags: pip, installation, python-3.5

When I try to install ftfy [here](https://github.com/LuminosoInsight/python-ftfy) package using command,
`pip install ftfy` I am getting following error in the terminal:

```
Collecting ftfy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d5/60/7b2d5d41ad6c6ebf48316b1c55ccf7c60d126e07f6306be9f254a139bfd1/ftfy-5.4.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/pytest-runner/: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:645) -- Some packages may not be found!
    Couldn't find index page for 'pytest-runner' (maybe misspelled?)
    Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:645) -- Some packages may not be found!
    No local packages or working download links found for pytest-runner
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/f4/sb0f69y118l8_xvhflgrgsjnrl5c1r/T/pip-install-uxw5kcal/ftfy/setup.py", line 62, in <module>
        'Documentation': 'http://ftfy.readthedocs.io',
      File "/Users/raja.charuvil/kattoor/ce-etl/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 139, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "/Users/raja.charuvil/kattoor/ce-etl/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 134, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "/Users/raja.charuvil/kattoor/ce-etl/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 514, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/Users/raja.charuvil/kattoor/ce-etl/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 777, in resolve
        replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting
      File "/Users/raja.charuvil/kattoor/ce-etl/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1060, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/Users/raja.charuvil/kattoor/ce-etl/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1072, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/Users/raja.charuvil/kattoor/ce-etl/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 581, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/Users/raja.charuvil/kattoor/ce-etl/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 670, in easy_install
        raise DistutilsError(msg)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pytest-runner')

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/f4/sb0f69y118l8_xvhflgrgsjnrl5c1r/T/pip-install-uxw5kcal/ftfy/
```

I am using Mac os and Python 3.5

I tried using solution from link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version) but that could not solve my issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install Python packages \[SSL: TLSV1\_ALERT\_PROTOCOL\_VERSION\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

Comment: Solution explained in that link could not solve my issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem got resolved after I update `pytest-runner package`.

`pip3 install pytest-runner --upgrade`

Then

`pip3 install ftfy`