# python setup.py cannot find required package

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, elastalert, gccfilter

I am following the setup for elastAlert here: https://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running_elastalert.html

when I run the command `python setup.py install --user` I get the error `error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('cffi>=1.11.5')`

So I attempted to solve this by running `pip install cffi --user`
When i run this command I get the output

```
Requirement already satisfied: cffi in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (1.11.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cffi) (2.19)
```

but then when I rerun `python setup.py install --user` I still get the same error:

```
Installing elastalert-rule-from-kibana script to /Users/Colin/Library/Python/2.7/bin
Installing elastalert-test-rule script to /Users/Colin/Library/Python/2.7/bin

Installed /Users/Colin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/elastalert-0.1.36-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for elastalert==0.1.36
Searching for cffi>=1.11.5
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'cffi' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for cffi>=1.11.5
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('cffi>=1.11.5')
```

Why can't this package be found?

```
python --version = Python 2.7.10
pip --version = pip 18.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

Comment: Please show the output of the failing `pip install` with `-v`. It should show the progress of looking for the distribution.

Comment: OK. I have added a larger portion of the output

Comment: I think you have an outdated OpenSSL.

What does this return:

```python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install Python packages \[SSL: TLSV1\_ALERT\_PROTOCOL\_VERSION\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

Comment: It looks like you're on MacOS, `python` is the system python (`/usr/bin/python`), also you have brewed `python2`. Your `pip` command installs packages for brewed python, so the system python won't see it. if you use brewed python explicitly, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/python setup.py install`, `cffi` installation will be found.

Comment: @hoefling thanks. I didn't have python2 in /usr/local/bin/python. However i did have a "pip2" in /usr/local/bin/ (1. so I think this means I installed pip2 with brew?). I ran "brew install python@2" then I ran "brew link --overwrite python@2". In my $PATH I have /usr/local/bin before /usr/bin. So I think you are correct that I was using a "brew pip2" and a "system python2"