# pip3 on MacOS: SSL error while installing virtualenv

Tags: python-3.x, macos, ssl, pip, virtualenv

when I run this command:

```
pip3 install virtualenv
```

It returns this:

```
Collecting virtualenv
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:645) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virtualenv (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for virtualenv
```

How can I fix it ?
Thank you for help

Comment: Try the `--verbose` mode and/or test the URL in a common browser if it works. Usually a browser like Firefox gives more detailed error messages on what went wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install Python packages \[SSL: TLSV1\_ALERT\_PROTOCOL\_VERSION\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

Answer (score 0):

this solved my problem:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python3
```

`pip3 install virtualenv`