# issues during jupyter install using pip on Python 2.7.3

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, installation, jupyter

We are using python 2.7.3 and do not have Anaconda available for install in the organization approved package list. So we have been trying to manually install the dependencies using unofficial windows binaries provided by Christoph Gohlke. Currently we are stuck at installing terminado-0.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl. This needs a  pywinpty package which is not available for Python 2.7.

We would appreciate any suggestions on how to proceed.

We would like to get Jupyter installed using any other possible option for  python 2.7.3

installing jupyter using pip gives below error so we went with manual route to install individual packages

60: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This pre
vents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL conne
ctions to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For
more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.ht
ml#ssl-warnings
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/jupyter/: There was a problem conf
irming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max
retries exceeded with url: /simple/jupyter/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ss
l.c:504: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol
 version'),)) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jupyter (from versions
: )
No matching distribution found for jupyter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install Python packages \[SSL: TLSV1\_ALERT\_PROTOCOL\_VERSION\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+tlsv1+alert+protocol+version

Comment: tried upgrading pip to latest version but it did not help. We  are on Windows 7

Comment: Upgrade `python` to at least 2.7.9, better 2.7.15.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue related to pywinpty package. Although the package was named with Python 3 convention, the documentation indicated that it supported 2.7. Changing the package name and running PIP solved the problem. Was able to complete Jupyter installation thereafter,

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Go to Python root folder and run the "Install Certificates.command" file.
2. Upgrade python version to 3.X.X and reinstall. You may follow https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BVS3U1OQzO4

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me on WIndows 10:

explicitly installing an older version of the package

```
PS> python2.exe -m pip install pywinpty==0.5.1
PS> python2.exe -m pip install notebook
PS> python2.exe -m pip install jupyter
```

Zero errors.

Reference:
https://pypi.org/project/pywinpty/0.5.1/