# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for pip

Tags: python, pip

I'm a beginner in python.
I already install python 2.7.5 , download get-pip.py file, using cmd and run these command and get this error:

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip

Can anyone help?

Comment: You shouldn't be installing Python 2.7, especially if you're just starting. The current version is 3.7, and it includes pip

Comment: Upgrade python to at least 2.7.9, better 2.7.15. Then upgrade pip.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install Python packages \[SSL: TLSV1\_ALERT\_PROTOCOL\_VERSION\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bpip%5d%20Could%20not%20find%20a%20version%20that%20satisfies%20the%20requirement