# Getting an error installing pip in my Mac

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install PIP package management system in my Mac but I am getting an error.

When I am writing a cod `sudo easy_install pip`, it is giving me following error:

```
Searching for pip
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: [SSL:
TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) -- Some packages may not be found! 
Couldn't find index page for 'pip' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/ Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) 
-- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for pip
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pip')
```

Can anyone help me to understand this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install Python packages \[SSL: TLSV1\_ALERT\_PROTOCOL\_VERSION\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+tlsv1+alert+protocol+version

Comment: It’s not duplicate, kindly use your energy in helping others instead giving them downvote

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easy solution is download and install the latest version of Python 3. Just grab the dmg from the website https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370/ Verify it was installed.

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.0
```

Pip is automatically included in this version so update it. Note use pip3 for Python 3.x

```
$ pip3 install --upgrade pip 
 Successfully uninstalled pip-10.0.1
 Successfully installed pip-18.0
```

Comment: yeah I have already downloaded python3 in my Mac... now I tried using pip3 install --upgrade pip and it worked well.. Thank you so much for this

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Make sure you installed python

```
$ python3 --version
```

Then install pip

```
$ python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip

$ python3 -m pip --version
```

for more check here:

https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/