# Unable to install pip because my Mac has python 2.7 by default

Tags: python, pip

I'm currently trying to download pip onto my python 3.9.6 I had downloaded off the official website, but my Macbook (version 10.15.6 Catalina) returns the line:

```
$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
$ python get-pip.py
ERROR: This script does not work on Python 2.7 The minimum supported Python version is 3.6. Please use https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py instead.
```

So I then tried installing python3 using the post [Getting an error installing pip in my Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54363239/getting-an-error-installing-pip-in-my-mac) which said to run the line:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.0
```

which installed python3 for me, and running $ python3 --version afterwards shows that I have Python 3.8.2 installed now. Yet then running the line returns that I can't install the packages due to:

```
$ pip3 install --upgrade pip Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/47/ca/f0d790b6e18b3a6f3bd5e80c2ee4edbb5807286c21cdd0862ca933f751dd/pip-21.1.3-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 19.2.3
    Uninstalling pip-19.2.3:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'RECORD'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 21.1.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Can anyone help me with this error? My account is an admin account already so I'm confused by what it means by check the permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have permission to install packages globally. Either use Sudo, or install for the current user only, as suggested in the command output you posted.

```
sudo pip3 install <package>
```

or

```
pip3 install --user <package>
```