# pip install installations failed

Tags: python, pip, centos, glibc

I am trying to install same packages by pip. But I get this:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:727)'),)': /pypi
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:727)'),)': /pypi
```

I try to solve it by these ways. But they don't work.

1) Add trusted-host. It does not work.

```
 --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org
```

2) Maybe it was caused by pip version or python version I think. Then I tried pip-19.3, pip-19.0, python-2.7.17, python-3.6.5. It does not work.

3) Update openssl to 1.1，and compile python with ssl. I get the error（both python-2.7.17, python-3.6.5） that I need to update libc to 2.17.

My os is centos 6.3. libc was 2.14. I have no root. Do I have to update libc?

Comment: There are many answers to this problem on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version . You mentioned it's a CentOS system on which you have no root--is there a system administrator you can contact?  If none of those answers work for you that would probably be your best bet, since it's unlikely anyone on SO can remotely debug your system's configuration.

Comment: Your OS, glibc and OpenSSL are too old to work with PyPI. You should consider [downloading python packages and dependencies from PyPI for offline installation on another machine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447068/7976758).

Comment: I have no permission to update os etc.  I compare it with other machine(on which pip works well).  Its centos version,  glibc version, ssl version is the same with my virtual machine. I don't know why pip on my machine does not work. @phd