# SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:661) - skipping-- Python

Tags: python, macos, pip

I have upgraded to Catalina 10.15  and have not install anything in my anaconda for a long time. Since yesterday, any pip or conda install I am trying to do is coming back with this

```
Collecting dtale
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/dtale/: There was a problem confirming the ssl 
certificate
[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:661) - skipping
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dtale (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for dtale
```

Above, I am trying to install the dtale library.

Could someone give me detailed steps of what to do, I am rubbish with the Shell, its jargon and that side of stuff.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not able to install Python packages \[SSL: TLSV1\_ALERT\_PROTOCOL\_VERSION\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+tlsv1+alert+protocol+version