# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyDispatcher-2.0.5 (from versions: none)

Tags: python, pip

Python 3.9.5
Here I go:

```
deactivate
rm -rf venv/
python -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
python -V
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install wheel
```

fine.
try this: in development.txt (has is PyDispatcher==2.0.5).

```
python -m pip install -r requirements/development.txt
```

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyDispatcher-2.0.5 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PyDispatcher-2.0.5
```

Why?

```
pip install PyDispatcher
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: PyDispatcher in /home/jonsl/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (2.0.5)
```

Is fine.

Comment: This post may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version

Comment: thanks @Eladtopaz thank you from your help. This does not know. `WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager.`